# Initializing Maple package in an "initialization file"

Tags: maple

I have a pretty simple question. I am trying to load a user-defined Maple package (GRTensor) every time I open Maple. Normally, I manually do it straight in Maple like so:

```
libname := "/home/user/maple2016/lib/grtensor/lib";
with(grtensor)
```

Which works perfectly fine, no issues.

Now, of course this is kind of a pain typing in every time I use Maple (often, as I do my research with it). So, I sought out the use of an [Initialization File](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=worksheet/reference/initialization) to automatically do this for me.  Following the steps under Linux, I created a file named "init" in my maple/lib directory, and put the following line of code in it:

```
libname := "/home/zack/maple2016/lib/grtensor";
```

Reopening Maple, should automatically initialize this package, yet I get a bunch of errors saying:

```
'HelpTools' does not evaluate to a module (in a popup box)
Error, 'Security' does not evaluate to a module (inline)
```

Then, when I try to run *anything* in Maple, I keep on getting the second error mentioned above.

Why does Maple freak out when I initialize the same library using an init file over doing it manually? Any ideas??

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to augment (prepend or append) to libname, not set it to just that location.

Maple still needs to be able to find its own .mla files, from its own default locations.

Try this instead,

```
libname := "/home/zack/maple2016/lib/grtensor", libname;
```

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much for your help :D